# How I can check the content of tuple tensor?

Tags: python, tuples

How I can check the content of tuple tensor? When we print its shape or size it says:

> Tuple object has no attribute  shape

or

> Tuple object has no attribute  size

Although with `len()` function we can check the length but its not showing any detail about the exact content of the tuple. For example I am printing the length of tuple named "sample"

```
print(" sample len",len(sample))
```

it shows the length which is two and  has one element on its 2nd dimension but no idea about the shape of first dimension shown as

```
sample len 2
 sample[1]  tensor(1.4000)
 sample [0] (tensor([[[[ 0.2649,  0.2296,  0.2453,  ..., -0.3939, -0.3939, -0.3939],
          [ 0.2610,  0.2414,  0.2335,  ..., -0.3861, -0.3822, -0.3822],
          [ 0.2570,  0.2374,  0.2453,  ..., -0.3743, -0.3743, -0.3743],
          ...,
```

Comment: A tuple, like a list, only knows about its own length and doesn't know about the shape (or anything else, really) of its children. In principle you could have children with different types, lengths, etc. so it doesn't make sense to define a tuple's "shape" as it does for e.g., a numpy array.

Comment: Tuples are very general 1-dimensional data structures and it may not make sense to talk about the *shape*of the data they contain. Your example only has a shape because of the multidimensional data you have put in it. The tuple itself contains simply references to 2 objects, that could be anything. And the Python convention is to provide an implementation of `len()` for anything for which that makes sense, rather than a `.size` attribute.